How to capture just the game area of a specific window in C++ (with opencv implementation)
I am trying to capture just the game area of a specific window.
Here is the code I have:
HWND GameWindowManager::findGameWindow() {
    HWND hwndGame = NULL;
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&hwndGame));
    return hwndGame;
}

BOOL CALLBACK GameWindowManager::EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    const DWORD TITLE_SIZE = 1024;
    WCHAR windowTitle[TITLE_SIZE];

    if (GetWindowText(hwnd, windowTitle, TITLE_SIZE) > 0) {
        std::wstring title(windowTitle);
        if (title.find(L"Game") != std::wstring::npos) {
            *(HWND*)lParam = hwnd;
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

cv::Mat GameWindowManager::captureGameWindow() {
    HWND hwnd = findGameWindow();
    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        qDebug() << "Game window not found.";
        return cv::Mat();
    }

    // get the client area of the Game window
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
    POINT topLeft = { rect.left, rect.top };
    POINT bottomRight = { rect.right, rect.bottom };

    // map the client area points to screen coordinates
    ClientToScreen(hwnd, &topLeft);
    ClientToScreen(hwnd, &bottomRight);

    // adjust rect to screen coordinates
    rect.left = topLeft.x;
    rect.top = topLeft.y;
    rect.right = bottomRight.x;
    rect.bottom = bottomRight.y;

    int width = rect.right - rect.left;
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    HDC hWindowDC = GetDC(hwnd);
    HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hWindowDC);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWindowDC, width, height);
    SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

    // copy from the window DC to the memory DC
    BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, width, height, hWindowDC, rect.left - topLeft.x, rect.top - topLeft.y, SRCCOPY);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = { 0 };
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = width;
    bi.biHeight = -height;  // negative height to flip the image
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 24;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    cv::Mat screen(height, width, CV_8UC3);
    GetDIBits(hMemoryDC, hBitmap, 0, height, screen.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hWindowDC);
    DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);

    return screen;
}

When I use opencv to print the frame for that window:
cv::imshow("Display Frame", gameplayScreen);

It displays the entire window including the title bar and its sidebar. I want it to capture only the game area within. OBS is able to do this easily, so I'm not sure what to do to accomplish this functionality. Also, I'm using Qt in my project as well.
Any help would be appreciated.

Since it is a game, are you sure the titlebar and sidebar are actually standard Windows elements and not custom elements being drawn by the game itself within the window's client area?

It's not clear the reason for using the qt tag, but if you're using it and you can get the winID of the target window, then you can use QScreen.grabWindow().

@musicamante I tried your suggestion and unfortunately the cv::imshow still displays the whole window with the title bar and everything. This is what I implemented using your suggestion:
QScreen* screen = QGuiApplication::screenAt(windowPosition);
if (!screen) {
    qDebug() << "No screen found.";
    return cv::Mat();
}

WId winId = reinterpret_cast<WId>(hwnd);
QPixmap capturedImage = screen->grabWindow(winId);
if (capturedImage.isNull()) {
    qDebug() << "Failed to capture the image.";
    return cv::Mat();
}


@RemyLebeau I believe it is a client area that is created by the game client itself, so may not be standard Windows elements. They have their own toolbar on the right side with plugins and such, so I'm assuming it's not a non-client area

@Zeriun "OBS is able to do this easily" - I'm not familiar with OBS, but I would imagine it either has an option to designate the area of a window to capture, or it has some presets for common games to know what areas to capture.

@RemyLebeau Yeah OBS is a video capture software for recording/streaming. When I target the specific game window (same window I target in my code) it's able to show only the game itself without the game client's title bar and tool bar. Also to note - when I do open up the toolbar on the game client and I see the frames from opencv, the display frame looks grey and distorted, almost as if it's getting minimized or something. But that doesn't happen with OBS. Not sure what it is.

@Zeriun cv::imshow() would still do the same as before, you need to check the capturedImage, and it is unclear if you actually get a valid pixmap or not (if it's valid, you obviously don't need to use cv::imshow() but the captured image instead). Please add code updates and debug info into your question (click the [edit] button).

Also to add - I noticed when I use the Greenshot screenshotting tool and I try to 'capture window' with it, I'm actually able to hover over the game itself and it will highlight that window without the game client's tool bar and such. I can also hover over the toolbar and it will highlight the entire game client window. So even Greenshot is able to determine the gameplay area itself

@Zeriun maybe check with UI Accessibility APIs if the game window offers any differentiation between its UI elements.

I was able to figure it out with just adjusting some margins in the screen capture. Since a tool like greenshot was able to capture the interior game window as well as the entire client itself, that allowed me to calculate the differences in the other UI elements (such as title bar) from the game window. With that, I came up with this solution:
cv::Mat GameWindowManager::captureGameWindow() {
HWND hwnd = findGameWindow();
if (hwnd == NULL) {
    qDebug() << "Game window not found.";
    return cv::Mat();
}

RECT rect;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

int topMargin = 29;  // adjust value as needed
int bottomMargin = 3;  // adjust value as needed
int leftMargin = 3;  // adjust value as needed
int rightMargin = 39;  // adjust value as needed

// adjust rect to exclude the UI elements
rect.top += topMargin;
rect.bottom -= bottomMargin;
rect.left += leftMargin;
rect.right -= rightMargin;

int width = rect.right - rect.left;
int padding = (4 - (width * 3 % 4)) % 4; // have to include padding - each pixel is 3 bytes for 24-bit bitmap
width += padding;
int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

HDC hWindowDC = GetDC(hwnd);
HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hWindowDC);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWindowDC, width, height);
SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, width, height, hWindowDC, rect.left, rect.top, SRCCOPY);

BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = { 0 };
bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bi.biWidth = width;
bi.biHeight = -height; // negative height to flip the image
bi.biPlanes = 1;
bi.biBitCount = 24;
bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;

cv::Mat screen(height, width, CV_8UC3);
GetDIBits(hMemoryDC, hBitmap, 0, height, screen.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

ReleaseDC(hwnd, hWindowDC);
DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);

return screen;}

Also had to include padding in there for the margins to properly be taken into account when doing the left and right margin calculations. I hope this helps anyone in the future that runs into a similar issue. Cheers.
